# Avoiding code-signing certificate if installing VSTO add-in with MSI

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

Is code signing a VSTO add-in required only when using ClickOnce for deploying/installing the add-in? I'm evaluating creation of a very simple MSI for add-in installation but will users see the warning dialog at first add-in loading/execution if not code signing the add-in?

Answer (score 0):

You will not get any warning dialog in case of MSI installers. The publisher will be unknown in that case, but no additional dialog will be shown to users. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) for more information.

Another advantage of signing add-in assemblies is that you will see a publisher's name in the COM add-ins dialog of Office applications.